# MsgBox if value in userform does not equal to ranges on sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a message box to appear if an entered value in my userform does not match any of the 5 cell values on my excel sheet. So far I got one to work for a single cell value but when I add "Or" for the other values it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub cmdEnterData_Click()

Dim raw1 As Range, raw2 As Range, raw3 As Range, raw4 As Range, raw5 As Range

Set raw1 = Range("A1")
Set raw2 = Range("A2")
Set raw3 = Range("A3")
Set raw4 = Range("A4")
Set raw5 = Range("A5")

' this one works for referencing a single cell value

If Trim(raw1.Value) <> Me.textbox_RawItem.Value Then
MsgBox "This item does not match the item list"
 With Me.textbox_RawItem
  .SetFocus
  .SelStart = 0
  .SelLength = Len(.Text)
 End With
 Exit Sub
End If

' this one does NOT work 

If Trim(raw1.Value) <> Me.textbox_RawItem.Vaule Or Trim(raw2.Value)<> 
Me.textbox_RawItem.Value Then
MsgBox "This item does not match the item list"
 With Me.textbox_RawItem
  .SetFocus
  .SelStart = 0
  .SelLength = Len(.Text)
 End With
 Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You have to add the comparison `<> Me.textbox..` to each part of the `IF/OR`

Comment: That is the answer. Please don't write answers in comments. It's misleading to people like me looking for unanswered questions.

Also, I'd add brackets around each individual comparison, just to make it more readable.

Comment: @ComradeMicha - it is indeed the answer - meant to be more a helpful hint since a full-blown answer (forthcoming) would address other issues with the code, including variable declaration (only raw5 is `Range`, all others are `Variant`.

Comment: Sorry, minor mistakes I didn't add to my code but I edited the original post to add the comparison code (2 comparisons only just to check code) and it still doesn't perform.

Comment: You also want `And` instead of `Or`

Comment: What "doesn't work" - error message?

Comment: BigBen, no "And" doesn't work because the value in the textbox is not required to contain all 5 of the cell values.

Comment: There is no error message, except my MsgBox keeps appearing even after inputting the correct value from one of the 5 cells.

Answer (score 0):

BigBen was right with using "And" instead of "Or". The code works as this:

```
Private Sub cmdEnterData_Click()

Dim raw1 As Range, raw2 As Range, raw3 As Range, raw4 As Range, raw5 As Range

Set raw1 = Range("A1")
Set raw2 = Range("A2")
Set raw3 = Range("A3")
Set raw4 = Range("A4")
Set raw5 = Range("A5")


If Trim(raw1.Value) <> Me.textbox_RawItem.Value And Trim(raw2.Value) <> 
Me.textbox_RawItem.Value And Trim(raw3.Value) <> Me.textbox_RawItem.Value And 
Trim(raw4.Value) <> Me.textbox_RawItem.Value And Trim(raw5.Value) <> 
Me.textbox_RawItem.Value Then
MsgBox "This item does not match the item list"
 With Me.textbox_RawItem
  .SetFocus
  .SelStart = 0
  .SelLength = Len(.Text)
 End With
Exit Sub
End If
```